# Printf or MessageBox in ASM for debugging

Tags: assembly, x86, windows-xp, x64dbg

I try to debug in x32dbg how a MFC program works with IO ports and I want to add printf or MessageBoxA after in/out assembly commands before returning from the function and display some values. When I put printf:

```
push eax //eax contains the value
call printf
add esp,4
ret
```

I get exception
`C0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`

If I use MessagrBoxA:

```
push 0 //OK
push eax // eax contains the value
push eax
push 0 // HWND
call dword ptr ds:[54352C] // linked user32.MessageBoxA
ret
```

I get the same exception into MessageBoxA. Why is this happens? How can I output some values another way?

**Update**:

If I use putchar here:

```
push eax
call putchar
add esp,4
ret
```

I get nothing because I didn't initialise console in my app. Is it possible to initialize it in ASM and run console parallel to main app?

Comment: You know that `printf` needs a format string, right? Similarly `MessageBox` takes strings not numeric values.

Comment: Yes, you can use [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) As to whether the C stdio will then automatically attach to that, I don't know.